# How to create an "islands" style pytorch matrix

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, boolean

Probably a simple question, hopefully with a simple solution:

I am given a (sparse) 1D boolean tensor of size `[1,N]`.

I would like to produce a 2D tensor our of it of size `[N,N]`, containing islands which are induced by the 1D tensor. It will be the easiest to observe the following image example, where the upper is the 1D boolean tensor, and the matrix below represents the resulted matrix:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Only an iterative solution, with a for loop over the indices of the True element.

Comment: it is torch.tensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a mask input:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0])
```

You can retrieve the indices with [`torch.diff`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diff.html):

```
>>> index = x.nonzero()[:,0].diff(prepend=torch.zeros(1), append=torch.ones(1)*len(x))
tensor([3., 5., 3.])
```

Then use [`torch.block_diag`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.block_diag.html) to create the diagonal block matrix:

```
>>> torch.block_diag(*[torch.ones(i,i) for i in index.int()])
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you. Please fix the small typo you have - b should be x.